# Flash under dhtml menu

Tags: flash, menu, dhtml, absolute

I'm struggling with this probelm for few hours and it's drives me crazy. I want my drop down menu put over flash area and it works but only in FF. Unfotunelly IE and Opera shows my menu under flash.

The DHTML menu system is the simplest as possible and it was wrote from scratch by me.

I've been trying everything, and still it doesn't work like it should.

I tried to put the flash element by jquery.flashEmbed script and by standard code with param transparent, but it never works. Plese help me, I'm loosing my head.

Here is the xhtml:

http://www.project.yamandi.com/toton/

Regards, 
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent`. The default value is `wmode=window` which will cause the flash element to always have a `z-index` greater than other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Put the flash in a div.

When your menu code is triggered, set style.display='none'; You might add some code to check if the menu overlaps the flash before hiding. when your menu is hidden again, reshow the flash. yes its ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for answer but I've finally found a solution.
I've read that put param tag with tranparent value can solve the problem, but this it's not. The solution is to put wmode="transparent" to EMBED TAG (!!!) like this:

This couse that flash object will be show under other layers of course with absolute positioning and hierarchial z-index values.

Regards, 
David